# Bootstrap dropdown to show grid

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show a list of clients in a dropdown, but I want their info separated into columns like FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, and Zip.

How can I put a grid in the dropdown and have each row be selectable like a regular dropdown? This is what I have so far, but the rows don't look right and only the "Create a new client" row has the correct highlighting when you hover over it.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="loadClientList()">
        {{client.DisplayName || "Select a client..."}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <div class="row" style="width: 650px;">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><b>First Name</b></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"><b>Last Name</b></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><b>Address</b></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><b>City</b></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"><b>State</b></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"><b>Postal</b></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ng-click="newClient()">[Create a new client]</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="c in clients">
            <div class="row" style="width: 650px;">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.FirstName}}</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.LastName}}</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.Address}}</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.City}}</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.StateCode}}</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"><a ng-click="selectClient(c)">{{c.PostalCode}}</a></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this Mega Menu, it's called Yamm: http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/