# Make Select Tag Display Options in a Box

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

By default the options displayed in a drop down are displayed one-by-one vertically like so: 
[image]

But is there a way that I can display the dropdown in a square where there are at least 5 symbols per line? My current code is as follows:

```js
<select id="symbolInLineSelector" (change)="insertSymbol($event.target.value)" class="ql-size" title="symbolSelect">
            <option
              *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)"
              [ngValue]="symbol"
              [innerHtml]="symbols[symbol]">
            </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be able to solve this by using the default `<select>` html element, which only serves pure 1-dimensional dropdowns. **A possibility** could be to use **bootstrap** dropdowns - in that case you might find what you need in the following thread:

[Bootstrap dropdown to show grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436377/bootstrap-dropdown-to-show-grid)